# There is a vector whose orthogonal complement is preserved under a linear map.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

### The problem:

Prove that for any non-zero $n$-dimensional matrix $A$ there is a non-zero vector $v \in \mathbb R^n$ such that for every $w \in \mathbb R^n$ we have $v \perp w \implies Av \perp Aw$.

### Attempted solutions:

I have tried a continuity approach, but it doesn't seem to generalise beyond $\mathbb R^2$. Using eigenvectors won't lead anywhere either, as there are non-diagonalisable matrices.

I will be grateful for any guidance.

Comment: Where does this come from?

Comment: A 10-year old exam question with no solution posted

Comment: I see nothing that rules out $v = 0$. Perhaps they define "$\perp$" so as to exclude it. But if so, then the statement would false for $A \equiv 0$.

Comment: You're right, I failed to exclude the trivial case. Edited now.

Comment: Care to respond to (or approve) the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix $A^\top A$ is a nonzero symmetric matrix and is in fact positive semidefinite. It has at least one positive eigenvalue $\lambda$. Choose $v$ to be an associated eigenvector. Can you finish now?

Comment: Oh, thank you, I see.
If $A^TAv=\lambda v$, then $\langle Av, Aw \rangle = \langle A^TAv,w\rangle = \lambda \langle v, w \rangle$.